# Count the No of Occurrences of a word in xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file in which I have to find the number of occurrences of a word i the XML file.
Consider, I have a sample XML file as below

```
<planes_for_sale>
   <ad>
      <year> 1977 </year>
      <make> &c; </make>
      <model> Skyhawk </model>
      <color> Light blue and white </color>
      <description> New paint, nearly new interior,
            685 hours SMOH, full IFR King avionics </description>
      <price> 23,495 </price>
      <seller phone = "555-222-3333"> Skyway Aircraft </seller>
      <location>
         <city> Rapid City, </city>
         <state> South Dakota </state>
      </location>
   </ad>
   <ad>
      <year> 1965 </year>
      <make> &p; </make>
      <model> Cherokee </model>
      <color> Gold </color>
      <description> 240 hours SMOH, dual NAVCOMs, DME, 
                new Cleveland brakes, great shape </description>
      <seller phone = "555-333-2222"  
              email = "jseller@www.axl.com">
              John Seller </seller>
      <location>
         <city> St. Joseph, </city>
         <state> Missouri </state>
      </location>
   </ad>
    <ad>
      <year> 1968 </year>
      <make> &p; </make>
      <model> Cherokee </model>
      <color> Gold </color>
      <description> 240 hours SMOH, dual NAVCOMs, DME, 
                new Cleveland brakes, great shape </description>
      <seller phone = "555-333-4444"  
              email = "jseller@www.axl.com">
              John Seller </seller>
      <location>
         <city> xxxxx, </city>
         <state> yyyyyy </state>
      </location>
   </ad>
</planes_for_sale>
```

Now, say I want to check for the number of occurrences of string "Gold" in the xml file.
How is that possible using C# code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that really what you want though?  What if the seller's surname is "Gold", or they live in Gold Beach? And what about if Gold is part of another word (Golden etc.)?  What information do you actually need to extract?

Comment: Thanks @DylanNicholson. Yes!I want to extract the number of occurrences of a string no matter in which part of word it is.

Comment: Read it into an XmlDocument, grab InnerText and search?

Comment: Ok, what about if Gold is part of the xml tag name, attribute name or comments?  If you really don't care, it's irrelevant that it's XML, and you can just read the whole file into a string and use `Regex.Matches(source, "Gold").Count`

Comment: have you tried an easy regex count?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I want to look for the occurrence of string in attributes as well along with inner text. I want to look for the number of occurrences of string in the entire XML file to be concise.

Comment: @Isitar : Never use regex on xml files.  xml is not regular and xml methods in net library are much easier to use the regex.

Comment: @jdweng in this case its just a text search, doesnt matter if the input is xml, json or whatevee

Comment: What is a person's name is Gold and it is in the email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've asked for, `Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(myFile), "Gold").Count` will do the job, probably more efficiently than anything you can write yourself.
But a more interesting problem is to find all planes whose Color property is Gold :)

(oh I forgot to ask about case sensitivity, but you can specify that in the 2nd parameter to Regex.Matches)

Answer (score 0):

Don't just look for Gold which may be in a person's name (emila address).  Your xml has ampersands which are not valid and give errors.  To get proper results use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("ad").Where(x => ((string)x.Element("color")).Trim() == "Gold").ToList();

            int count = results.Count;

        }
    }
}
```